# How to avoid having to use the tilde with every macro?

Tags: spacing, macros, xspace

I am relatively new to LaTeX, so please bear with me.

I have just started using macros and finding them quite useful. However, I find myself having to use the tilde (`~`) a lot of times to get a space between the macro defined string and the next word.

Example:

```
\newcommand{\ftp}{File Transfer Protocol}
```

but when I write this:

```
The \ftp is awesome because blah blah blah.
```

I get this (note there isn't a space between 'Protocol' and 'is'):

```
The File Transfer Protocolis awesome blah blah blah.
```

so I have to use the tilde:

```
the \ftp~is awesome because blah blah blah.
```

so that I can get that space:

```
The File Transfer Protocol is awesome blah blah blah.
```

**My question is then:** is there anyway I can avoid having to type the tilde every time?

Comment: Have a look at the `xspace` package.

Comment: That looks like what I am looking for yes. However, it doesn't show up on the MikTeX package manager... Am I supposed to install it manually or sth? Thanks.

Comment: @nunos It should be installed as it belongs to the required tools package. Also, do not use `~` here as it forces a space that is not breakable. Better would be ``\ ``.

Comment: Hm.. Can you please take a look here then? http://pastebin.com/q4KVFdMX. I am still not getting a space after the macro. Thanks.

Comment: @nunos Have you seen the linked duplicated question? You need to actually use `\xspace`: `\newcommand{\foobar}{Foobar\xspace}`

Comment: Another option, which I quite like, is to write `the {\ftp} is awesome...`. The advantage of this over `~` or `\ ` is that it's independent of whether your macro is followed by a space or a punctuation mark. E.g. `I like {\ftp} and more {\ftp}.`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel you're so right. I skimmed through the duplicate question and thought it would work just by using the package. It works now with the `\xspace`. Thanks.